# How do I place these divs in the same row?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a web page with topics, and I want to have four topics in each row. I've put 4 dummy topics, but they align in a column to the left, instead of in a row, like so:

[image: screenshot of the webpage]

This is the CSS code I used:

```
.Topic{
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #F2EECB;
  margin: 2%;
}

.Topics{
  background-color: red;
  display: grid;
  gridTemplateColumns: auto auto;
}
```

And this is the JSX code I used to render the topics:

```
function Topics(){

var TopicsList = TopicsDB.map(topic => 
    <div className="Topic" style={divStyles}>
        <h2> {topic.Name} </h2>
    </div>
    )


return <div className="Topics">
        {TopicsList}
        </div>
        }
```

Where Topics is the red parent div, and Topic are the individual topics.

Tried using different variations of grid display and columns arrangement, to no avail.

Comment: `display :flex` on the parent?

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  outline: 2px dashed blue;
  display: inline-block;
  
  height: 48px;
  width: 56px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your divs or topics are shown in one row instead of multiple rows, you could use `display:flex` on the parent div, then you set `flex-direction: column` and this will show each one of them in a column like the screenshot you attached

Answer (score 0):

Just change your css to this:

```
.Topics {
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.Topic {
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #f2eecb;
    margin: 2%;
}
```

I think it can help you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
display: inline-block;
```

For Topics